# animating from UITableViewCell to a modal view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a horizontal UITableView and it has a subclass of a UITableViewCell. I am trying to have an animation where if someone taps on the UITableViewCell the cell does a backflip animation and resizes into a modal view. How and what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can actually perform exactly what you want using UIView's class method:

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

You could do the following:

- Create a clone of the UITableViewCell that has been pressed
- Overlay it on the table view at exactly the same position as the pressed cell
- Call the method above using the 'from' view as the cloned cell view and the 'to' view as the new 'modal' view (a view that fills the screen).

I recommended that you create a clone otherwise the cell is removed from the tableview:

> The starting view for the transition. By default, this view is removed from its superview as part of the transition.

edit: I forgot to mention, the animation that you're looking for is `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom`

Comment: How do I create a UIView which is a clone of the UITableViewCell?

Comment: Depending on how you set up your UITableViewCell you could try accessing the cell.contentView property.

Comment: You could also create a UIImage of the UITableViewCell contentView - http://pastie.org/244916, then instantiate a UIImageView and position it accordingly.